# Date picker doesn't work for dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, datepicker

the Jquery UI date picker doesn't work with dd.mm.yyyy format. Is there any way to make it work?

Please test

```
Date 1: <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" class="date" value="">
Date 2: <input type="text" name="date2" id="date2" class="date" value="">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.date').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker({ changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,maxDate: "+0D"});
        $(this).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yyyy" );
    });  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sateeshchandrach/T2u5v/3/

Sorry updated question again and is there any way to make Jquery UI to work with 4y's in date format.

Comment: Did you read documentation/API at all? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: To be fair, the jquery UI documentation link is broken at this time.  The datepicker references the dateFormat function but the links don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong.

JS:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy" );
```

HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" /></p>
```

Example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9EhDx/

The list of valid date formatting strings can be found in the JQuery [formatdate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) documentation.

```
The format can be combinations of the following:
    d - day of month (no leading zero)
    dd - day of month (two digit)
    o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
    oo - day of the year (three digit)
    D - day name short
    DD - day name long
    m - month of year (no leading zero)
    mm - month of year (two digit)
    M - month name short
    MM - month name long
    y - year (two digit) 
    yy - year (four digit)
    @ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
    ! - Windows ticks (100ns since 01/01/0001)
    '...' - literal text
    '' - single quote
    anything else - literal text
```

Comment: thanks i was not adding format as an option. but what is error in my way adding date format

Comment: @ChandraZ 4 ys in your format will not get you a 4 digit year.  The documentation states that 2ys gives you a 4 digit year.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your own custom format to Jquery UI.

In your dateFormat you are using YYYY instead of YY,

The docs over at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate contain the proper format:

y - year (two digit)
yy - year (four digit)

Your code should be:

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#date").datepicker({ changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,maxDate: "+0D",dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2u5v/4/

Comment: Why do you want .yyyy? YY is the 4 digit representation of the year.

Comment: The way dateFormat works is y = year (two digit) and yy = year (four digit)

Comment: I need to work with dd.mm.yyyy format as my application uses the same format driven by database. And I cannot change it for my use.

Comment: YY is equal to a 4 digget date.